# Custom object as an Opportunity attribute in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

1. The user must be able to add multiple Service Locations(custom object in SF) to an Account
2. Once an opportunity is created for the account, the user must be able to add service locations from the list of locations that are associated with that account

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to attach service locations to account:
You can create a junction object between account and service location objects. Then add a related list for this junction object on account layout. Also create a validation/trigger to ensure that the junction object cannot be created without opportunity.

If you want to attach service locations to opportunity:
Create the junction object between opportunity and service location objects.

Creating junction objects : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_manytomany.htm&language=en&type=0

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How do I ensure that the user associates only those service locations that are added to the Account? Is there a way to do a lookup before adding?

Comment: The Junction object will have lookups/master-detail relation to opportunity and service location objects. Yes, you will select service location as a lookup while creating junction object record from account page. You can add lookup filter if you need simple validation or add a validation rule on junction object. something like `JUNCTION.accountID == Opportunity.accountID`